# How to Pass each value of an array as parameter to a get request call, and save all response in together in one json format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, rest

How do i pass values from an array, as parameters to a get request REST api call and save all responses received, for each item per api request.

I have the following file format:

```
Const Data = [
  {
      user: '123456'
     
    },
   
  { 
      user: '123456',
    
    },
   
  {
      user: '123456',
     
    },
   

  }
]
```

the get url for the API is:

```
router.get(`/courses/:user)
```

What i'm trying to do:

pass all values of Data as parameter to the request, so it will look like this:

`localhost:8000/courses/123456`

This will happen for as many items in data, then gather together all the responses in on json output.

I have tried using `forEach` but no luck so far.

Expected result should be a Json data  with all responses:

```
var output = [{response1},{response2}, {responds3}]
```

Comment: Call `fetch()` in a loop, saving the returned promises in an array. Then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of them to finish, and make an array of the results.

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you help with a code example?

Comment: I'm trying to find a previous question that already answers this. I'm sure it's been asked many times.

Comment: Found none though cos i checked, if you find any, kindly share please.
Many Thanks.

Comment: I can find lots of them that use jQuery, it's harder to find non-jQuery instances. Although the general idea should be the same, just replace `$.ajax` with `fetch` and `$.when` with `Promise.all`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Data = [
  {
      user: '123456'
     
    },
   
  { 
      user: '123456',
    
    },
   
  {
      user: '123456',
     
    },
  }
];

const result = await Promise.all(Data.map(({user}) => apiCall(user)));
```